# What does this inner join query exactly mean?

Tags: mysql

I'm often on this site to find answers and I usualy find what I look for but this time it's really particular so I post.

I'm working on a code I didn't write and I'd like somebody to explain me in detail what does the following query mean :

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM ( SELECT Id_dormir 
       FROM (dormir INNER JOIN dormir_photo AS DP 
             ON Id_dormir = Id_dormir_photo) INNER JOIN communes as C ON 
             Commune_dormir = Id_commune  
       WHERE  Type_dormir=3 
       GROUP BY Id_dormir, Commune_dormir ) AS T
```

I'l not a boss in mysql and all those inner join and as are not very clear (it's a query from a search engine.

If anyone can help, many thanks,
Laurent

Comment: 1.you use more subqueries that'll be performance issue

Comment: @Vijaykumar_Hadalgi Why? Subquery is not a sufficient condition to have bad performance. SQL have smart optimizations and indexes to make subquerys run faster.

Answer (score 1):

The outer query count a number of rows, returned by inner query:

```
SELECT Id_dormir FROM dormir
    INNER JOIN dormir_photo AS DP ON Id_dormir = Id_dormir_photo
    INNER JOIN communes as C ON Commune_dormir = Id_commune 
WHERE  Type_dormir=3 GROUP BY Id_dormir, Commune_dormir
```

In this query author get information from 3 tables:
`domir`, `domir_photo`, but only rows, where `Id_dormir_photo = Id_dormir` and from `communes` rows, where `Commune_dormir = Id_commune`. Than he filter rows with `Type_dormir=3` and groups  this with `Id_dormir, Commune_dormir` to have only UNIQUE rows with `Id_dormir, Commune_dormir`.

Your query count rows, where unique pair of `Id_dormir, Commune_dormir` and isset records in `dormir_photo` and `communes`.

I recommend you to read about different types of `JOIN` operation, especially about `INNER JOIN` (standard JOIN) and `LEFT JOIN`, this types are most applicable.

Comment: So quickly ! Many thanks. In that case if there's some rows in the dormir table that have no match in the dormir_photo table those rows won't be in the result ?

Comment: Yes. If you want to have this rows, you must use `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: Is there a way to add a 'solved' on the answer title ?

Comment: Click on green tick to the side of the answer.